# I want to change the text dat "lampp" in opt/lampp (I installed xampp), but i can't

Tags: nautilus, lamp, permissions

I tried to change the rights of the folder "lampp", heres a screenshot:

[image]

I also pressed "Zugriffsrechte auf enthaltene Datein übertragen" (Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files).

What did I do wrong?

Sorry for my bad english, i'm german ;-)

Comment: What was your intend? Why did you want to change the permissions of the folder?

-- German -- was genau wolltest du überhaupt machen? Warum wolltest du die Rechte von dem Ordner ändern? (Antworte auf Englisch, wenn es dir möglich ist, damit dir weiterhin so viele wie möglich helfen können)

Answer (score 0):

- Open a terminal by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>
- Type `sudo mv /opt/lampp /opt/xampp`
- Type your password when prompted. Type it blind. It wont show. Hit Enter when done.

This will change the folder name to xampp from lampp.

> Use with caution. Changing the name can affect other applications or scripts which try to search lampp

Comment: But I dont wont to change the folder name

Comment: @johnsmith Sorry, misunderstood your question then. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, my english is bad ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to change a text dat in the folder opt/lampp

Comment: @johnsmith then use `gksudo xdg-open <filename>`